# WhatsApp Web Logged in computers

Tags: whatsapp

I usually only use WhatsApp on my phone but today I needed to write a longer message and decided to use WhatsApp Web. To my surprise, when I went to scan the barcode, I saw that WhatsApp Web was already connected on another computer running Windows 7. I have Windows 10 on my laptop and so does everyone else in my household. It happened to me before, several months ago. Back then, it also listed a Windows 7 computer and I clicked "log out from all computers". I kept coming back to check if any computers were connected for a while but didn't see anything suspicious so I forgot about it. Seeing it again today makes me wonder what can it be? Can it be a bug or does it mean someone hacked me and is reading my messages? The messages don't appear read unless I read them myself.... Is there anything I can do to make sure this other computer cannot log in as me in the future?

Comment: This looks like a question for Whatsapp support. "What is this computer listed on this vendor's service?" is not a question people who are not connected to the service can answer.

Comment: Also, keep your phone locked and never leave if unattended.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I wasn't sure where to post this question but you are right that Whatsapp support is where I should have started. I don't usually leave my phone unattended but I will be extra careful now and will get a password to unlock as well.